# How to get all the prices from a particular column add them and print them

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a column name(selling price) in a database which contains all the prices of a product now what i want is to add all the selling prices and display the total selling price.

for example: Selling price column contains

```
Selling price
-------------
580
580
20
```

i want to  add all the selling prices and display the total in the case the total will be 1180.

```
try {
     Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/customerinfo", "root", "");
     Statement st = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs;
     String mysqlQuery = "SELECT `sellingprice` FROM cust_info";
     rs =st.executeQuery(mysqlQuery);
     while(rs.next()) {
        String total = rs.getString("sellingprice"); // getting all the selling prices
          //converting to integer
          int totalValue = Integer.parseInt(total);
          // what logic should goes here....
          System.out.println(totalValue);    
     }
 }catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

Comment: you can use *sum* function, SELECT SUM(`sellingprice`) FROM cust_info.
the function returns you the sum directly

Answer (score 2):

You can just use SUM in the query like in the comment above or you can do the following:

```
try {
 Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/customerinfo", "root", "");
 Statement st = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs;
 String mysqlQuery = "SELECT `sellingprice` FROM cust_info";
 rs =st.executeQuery(mysqlQuery);

 int totalValue = 0;
 while(rs.next()) {    
     totalValue += rs.getInt("sellingprice");
 }
 System.out.println"The total Value is: " + totalValue; 
}catch(Exception e) {
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I changed the following

`rs.getInt`  instead of `rs.getString` , you can also use `getDouble` depending on the data you are expecting.

declare and initialize the int variable before the loop and increment it within the loop.

print the total after the loop has finished.

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
     Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/customerinfo", "root", "");
     Statement st = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs;
     String mysqlQuery = "SELECT `sellingprice` FROM cust_info";
     rs =st.executeQuery(mysqlQuery);
     while(rs.next()) {
        String total = rs.getString("sellingprice"); // getting all the selling prices
          //converting to integer
          int totalValue = Integer.parseInt(total);//<----- YOUR PROBLEM
          // what logic should goes here....
          System.out.println(totalValue);    
     }
 }catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

You can't create your `totalValue` in your `while` statement.  Each time the code cycles through the while statement, you're going to reset the total value to the latest `total` you got from your resultset.  You want something like:

```
 try {
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/customerinfo", "root", "");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
            String mysqlQuery = "SELECT `sellingprice` FROM cust_info";
            rs =st.executeQuery(mysqlQuery);
            int totalValue = 0; //<-- Create your total value outside of the while statement.
            while(rs.next()) {
                String total = rs.getString("sellingprice");
                totalValue += Integer.parseInt(total);//<-- Add the selling price from the current row to the total.
                System.out.println(totalValue); //<--This will print the latest total for each row in your result set
            }
            System.out.println(totalValue); //<-- This will print only the final total
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution , using the SUM function :

```
try {
 Connection con = (Connection) 
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/customerinfo", "root", "");
 Statement st = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs;
 String mysqlQuery = "SELECT SUM(`sellingprice`) FROM cust_info";
 rs =st.executeQuery(mysqlQuery);
 int totalValue  = 0;
 if(rs.next()) {
      String total = rs.getString("sellingprice");
      if(total != null){
          totalValue  = Integer.parseInt(total);    
      }
      System.out.println(totalValue);
 }
 }catch(Exception e) {
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```